# Will different website A/B tests interfere with either test's results?

Tags: web, ab-testing

I have a question about running an A/B test against different pages on a website and if I should worry about them interfering with either test's results. Not that it matters, but I'm using Visual Website Optimizer to do the testing.

For example, if I have two A/B tests running on different pages in the order placement flow, should I worry about the tests having an effect on one anothers goal conversion rate for the same conversion goal? For example, I have two tests running on a website, one against the product detail page and another running on the shopping cart. Ultimately I want to know if a variation of either page affects the order placement conversion rate. I'm not sure if I should be concerned with the different test's results interfering with one another if they are run at the same time.

My gut is telling me we don't have to worry about it, as the visitors on each page will be distributed across each variation of the other page. So the product detail page version A visitors will be distributed across the A and B variations of the cart, therefore the influence of the product detail page's variation A on order conversion will still be measured correctly even though the visitor sees different versions of the cart from the other test. Of course, I may be completely wrong, and hopefully someone with a statistics background can answer this question more precisely.

The only issue I can think of, is a combination between one page's variation and another page's variation worked together better than other combinations. But this seems unlikely.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining the issue clearly enough, so please let me know if my question makes sense. I searched the web and Stackoverflow for an answer, but I'm not having any luck finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and there is no quick answer to it and it depends on the types of test you are running. There are times that A/B tests on different pages influence each other, specially if they are within the same sequence of actions, e.g. checkout.

A simple example, if on your first page, variation A says "Click here to view pricing" and variation B says "Click here to get $500 cash". You may find that click through on B is higher and declare that one successful. Once the user clicks, on the following page, there are asked to enter their credit card details, with variations being "Pay" button being either green or red. In a situation like this, people from variation A might have a better chance of actually entering their CC details and converting as opposed to variation B who may feel cheated.

I have noticed when websites are in their seminal stages and they are trying to get a feel of what customers respond to well, drastic changes are made these multivariate tests are more important. When there is some stability and traffic, however, the changes tend to be very subtle and overall message and flow are the same and A/B tests become more micro refinements. In those cases, there might be less value in multi page cross testings (does background colour on page one means anything three pages down the process? probably not!).

Hope this answer helps!